# Remove event handler used by .ajaxStop

Tags: jquery

If I attach an event handler using .ajaxStop like this:

```
$(document).ajaxStop(function() {
    //Some code
});
```

How do I remove that event handler?

Comment: may be `.off()` or `.unbind()` will help

Comment: and what would be the exact code to use in this case??

Comment: see you have answer for that

Answer (score 17):

Try unbinding it, like so:

```
$(document).ajaxStop(function () {
    $(this).unbind("ajaxStop");
    //Some code
});
```

It's how I've been doing it.

Comment: I needed to use `$(document).unbind('ajaxStop');` rather than `$(this)`.

Comment: jQuery's `unbind` is deprecated as of version 3.0, use `off` instead.

Comment: This worked great. If you're only looking to have this fire once, then look at using `$(document).one("ajaxStop", function () { ... } )` instead. Much cleaner than unbinding the event handler afterwards.

Answer (score 3):

use [.off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/)

> Remove an event handler.

```
$("#elementID").off()
```

this removes all event handler from the selected element

Comment: for that you need to provide us with codes and tell us what actaully you need.. which event you are talking about?? and so on

Comment: I want the .ajaxStop handler to stop executing the code that I gave it

Comment: Ok.  I see what your saying.  I just figured it out:  $(document).off("ajaxStop");

Comment: What if you had 2 events?  How would you shut just one of them off?

Comment: `$("#elementID").off("click");`.. please go through the docs.. that will help you a lot..

Comment: @e-zero To actually answer your question, you can namespace your event handlers: `$(document).on('ajaxStop.yournamespace', callback)` and `$(document).off('ajaxStop.yournamespace')`.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to ensure that the handler code inside ajaxStop() method is executed **before** it is removed, I propose the following:

```
$(document).ajaxStop(function(){    
    // Functions there

    $(this).unbind("ajaxStop");
});
```

Particulary useful if you have various possible $.ajax in the same page and you want to control where to execute the ajaxStop() code. Then you just have to use this code inside the needed jQuery function.

Comment: jQuery's `unbind` is deprecated as of version 3.0, use `off` instead.